# How to remove this annoying Push Changes button in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It wasn't there before, for something reason it appeared in my vscode recently, maybe after an update.

So anyone knows how to remove these buttons?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the Visual Studio Code version? I have 1.61.2 from 2021-10-19 and the button is not there. You might have extensions which cause displaying the button or your repo is set up like a package and can be published? Not sure.

Comment: what is the purpose of those buttons, because you have the same button in the title bar, can you find a setting in the SCM section to turn it off

Comment: Oh wait there was an announcement message in the changelog. I'll post as answer.

Comment: Thanks @PeterKrebs it worked!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of v1.69, there is [new setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_commit-action-button-for-git-repositories) to enable/disable these git commit/publish/sync buttons.

[image: setting to enable or disable git action buttons]  or this setting in your `settings.json`:

```
"git.showActionButton": {
  "commit": false,
  "publish": false,
  "sync": false
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> **NOTICE:** Outdated since 1.69, see answer from Mark

The Visual Studio Code changelog for 1.61 has you covered:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61#_publish-or-sync-action-button-for-git-repositories

To quote the last section:

> users can customize this behavior by configuring the `git.showUnpublishedCommitsButton` setting,
> ...
> And finally, users can completely disable the visibility of any action buttons in the Source Control view via the new `scm.showActionButton` setting, which overrides any Source Control extension's behavior.

So for example, look in *"Settings > Features > SCM > Show Action Button"* or search for `showActionButton` in the "Search settings" field.

I don't know why the button is not showing up for me, so I cannot conform it is the correct setting - but this should be what you are looking for.

Comment: This answer is now out of date