# Hide the Commit & Push button in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control, push, commit

After the latest VS Code update there is the `Commit & Push` button. How could I hide it to have my IDE as it was before?

[image]

Comment: read the re;lease notes to see if there is a setting added to hide the button, or search the settings for `commit`

Comment: @rioV8, tried searching for the `commit` - no success. Where could I read the release notes?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72777515/836330

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a configuration in VS Code for this.
[There is setting in vs code to hide this action button by unchecking this you can hide the button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkY3n.png)

You may also read the release notes from VS Code for the same. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_commit-action-button-for-git-repositories