Commit button has disappeared from source control in vscode, how can I get it back?
Recently I went to update my site in vscode. After making a few changes I saved the file, but realized all the changes were stuck in pending.

After messing around some, the pending changes showed up under staged, but are still listed as pending. Even so, I still have not commit button. So with everything in pending and now commit button, I cannot make changes to my site. I have opened other files I have and they can take changes and commit just fine. So I can't figure out what to do to fix this.

Can you not just use command+enter?

did you accidentally disable it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69740460/11107541 check scm.showActionButton and git.showActionButton settings.

Can you try 'git add' for one of the files? Assuming you want to keep the changes to the HTML file.
